# Open for writing and reading a large file Python

Tags: python, file, large-files

I'm trying to read a large binary file (>5 GB) using `os.open`, `mmap` and `from_buffer()`.

Running `fd = os.open(filePath, O_RDWR)` the error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: H:\\xyz.wdp` raised. I realised that the problem was that the file was too large, since using similar but smaller files, `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDONLY`, it worked.
Unfortunately, if I use `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDONLY`, access is denied for `from_buffer()` function (`TypeError: mmap can't modify a readonly memory map.`).

My example code is:

```
class StructData(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('bin', c_ubyte)]

fd = os.open(filePath, os.O_RDWR)
mmap_file = mmap.mmap(fd, length=80, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, offset=0)
d_array = StructData*80
data = d_array.from_buffer(mmap_file)
```

Could you help me to fix this problem? I want to add I work with large files, and I need it runs really fast, I'd like to avoid using `struct.unpack` and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: How about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Without more information, it is very difficult to figure out your problem. However, it seems that the filePath variable has a syntax error, so if you write what you are storing in it, it would be very useful.

Comment: I updated my question with an example code

Comment: Pablo, what value are you passing to _filePath_? That variable is raising the error, and it is important that you write what is its content

Comment: My real filePath value is `'H:\\LiDAR\\CASTELLON_LID3\\LAS1.3_Full_Waveform\\CASTELLON_150916_120740.wdp'` (I wrote a shorter example). I don't think the error it's due to this value, since I try with the same path but changing to `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY` or other files within the same directory but smaller than 4GB and it works in `O_RDWR` mode.

Comment: Pablo, the Error message you are getting is related to the path argument. There should be a syntax error somewhere

Comment: I can use `os.O_RDONLY` and `os.O_WRONLY`with the same path argument, and `os.O_RDWR` for similar files but smaller than 4GB. Therefore, I guess it's because of it can't read and write files bigger than 4 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the path it seems like you're using Windows.
The documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) says that one should use os.O_BINARY to open files in binary mode on Windows.
Have you tried the following? (In case you might be creating the file...)

```
fd = os.open(filePath, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_BINARY)
```

I don't know the situation in Windows about large file support:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/posix.html

Comment: Yeah! It worked! In my case I don't create a new file, I just read it, but `from_buffer()` can't work with just `os.O_RDONLY`. I then used `os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY` and it worked! It's important that mmap access is in `mmap.ACCESS_WRITE` too. Thank you!